# Several faulty modems or something else?

Tags: networking, router, internet

Our internet is provided by CenturyLink and for the most part the internet works fine for our needs. We pay for up to 8 mbps and usually get that. However, in the past couple months we have gone through three of their routers.

First was a `PK5100Z` that functioned well for a couple years until a couple months ago where it had to be restarted a couple times a week. It also had an issue with passive FTP connections around the same time. Calling in to the provider we then received a `C1100Z` and after setup seemed to work good for the first couple days then the same issues returned and was even worse. It had to be restarted every single day, sometimes twice. This lasted about a couple weeks until we called them for a new router and they mailed us another `C1100Z`. Thinking the first one may have been faulty too we installed the new one. Not even a day went by and it had to be rebooted like the previous two. This one must be rebooted 1-2 times a day.

1. `PK5100Z` - Had to be rebooted couple times a week. Stopped working with passive FTP.
2. `C1100Z` #1 - Rebooted almost daily.
3. `C1100Z` #2 - Rebooted 1-2 times a day. Goes 'offline' often.

When it slows down and needs to be rebooted it is either offline or our download speed has gone from what we pay for down to ~10 to 80 kbps or worse. A reboot usually fixes it temporarily.

Our household has a few devices on at a time but something it should be able to handle. Three laptops and three smartphones - rarely all on at the same time. The most going on is usually Netflix or Youtube.

When looking in the router [`DSL Status` page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahE5t.jpg) both C1100Zs had the same errors/error rates. Unavailable seconds in that album means it has been offline for almost 5 and a half hours. On every reboot both `C1100Z`s always have a Link Train Error and is offline for 59 seconds.

Are we just getting faulty routers from CenturyLink? Should we purchase a router from somewhere else (such as DD-WRT)? Could it be the lines in our house or something else? If its the lines, why does rebooting the router seem to fix it if only temporarily?

Comment: Have they tested the lines from the outside of your home to the ISP? If they have just been replacing the modem and haven't done any tests on the lines, they aren't doing their job. The reason the reset of the modem works is because a bunch of error bits eventually build up and it causes the connection to drop. By resetting the modem, the error bit count resets and won't go down again until it meets the threshold.

Comment: Well, when we got the first C1100Z it looked like the repair-man they sent had checked up by the electric pole and then the box inbetween the three houses on our road. He did not say anything was wrong if there was and he just gave us a new router from their truck.

Comment: They would more than likely tell you that there was something wrong with the outside lines. I worked with one extremely lazy guy and he never even lied about the outside lines conditions. It could be an inside line problem. You could have them test the lines inside of the home, but that usually carries a fee. You could also have them simply test your Ethernet cable that is going from the wall to the router. They should do that one free of charge.

Comment: I remember hearing that the lines inside our house were pretty old. Another repair-man is actually coming later today to check the lines inside the house. I'll make an update afterwards.

Comment: @DrZoo The boxes all along the way to our area were checked; two of them had their cables replaced. I will come back in a day or two if nothing has changed.

Comment: Nice. During the short amount of time I was with a CenturyLink outside plant tech, 99% of the time the cable problems occurred out in the field, rather than in the customers home. Hopefully this turns out to be the same case for you.